# java.sql.DatabaseMetaData.getPrimaryKeys() returns empty result

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc, metadata

I'm working on spring boot and use JdbcTemplate.
I need to get table column names at runtime.
why the getPrimaryKeys() returns empty records?
My target database is SQL Server.
My codes are here...

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/db")
public class WebPosDBController {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    // ...

    private void loadMetadata(DBRecord dbRecord) {

    try {
        Connection conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
        DatabaseMetaData dm = conn.getMetaData();

        ResultSet rs = dm.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, dbRecord.getTablename());
        List<String> pkNames = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            // NEVER GET HERE
            pkNames.add(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
        }
        rs.close();

        rs = dm.getColumns(null, null, dbRecord.getTablename(), null);
        List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
        fieldNames.add(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
        }
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Which JDBC driver are you using? ...Microsoft's? ...jTDS? ...?

Comment: Show the DDL of the table and replace your code with the simplest version possible (ie: use hardcoded values instead of `dbRecord.getTablename()` so we can see the values used)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the schema when asking for the primary keys.

```
String schema = "your_schema_name"
ResultSet rs = dm.getPrimaryKeys(null, schema, dbRecord.getTablename());
```

It might be that your SQL Server uses a default schema for all the databases you create, which might be dbo, or the username that is used to connect to the database.